# How to completely read a file bigger than 4GB in Windows?

Tags: visual-c++

I need to process many files bigger than 4GB in Windows.
I use FILE and fread() to read one file (about 40GB), and compile my code in VS2010, Debug-x64, but the file cannot be read completely.

As I've found in C++ lib's source file, the members in FILE struct are in 32bit (int), so I found why it failed, but what should I do to make the file be read completely?

Comment: Do you have 40 GB contiguous memory allocated? If not you can read the file in parts, and that would be recommended.

Answer (score 0):

If you only are concerned about running on Windows, you can use a CFile object. Its members are 64-bit.

Comment: The use the Win32 API functions for files. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364232(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @JoeWillcoxson: `CFile` does not have a 64-bit [Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctka0kks(v=vs.120).aspx) function.

Comment: You can't expect to read a 40GB file with one read call.  You read it in chunks of course.  The Seek() and  and GetPosition() members are 64-bit which allows you to seek anywhere in the file.