# C++ Read 6.32 GB file at once

Tags: c++

Which function to use to read 6.32 GB file into an array at once. ReadFile function is limited to DWORD only.

```
DWORD bytes_to_read, bytes_read;
ReadFile(handle, src, bytes_to_read, &bytes_read, nullptr);
CloseHandle(handle);
```

[ReadFile function, Windows Dev Center](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Do you need to have 6.32 GB of data in your program at once or can you process pieces of the data file?

Comment: Search the internet for "msdn memory mapped file c++".

Comment: Is there anything that prevents you from calling `ReadFile` more than once?

Comment: You may want to use a `std::vector<DWORD>` and pre-allocate the amount of space (slots), or declare a `static` array or dynamically allocate an array.

Comment: possible unanswered dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411916/how-to-completely-read-a-file-bigger-than-4gb-in-windows

Comment: What's wrong with using `std::ifstream` and the `read` member function?

Comment: @Thomas
I am reading text data into an array created by VirtualAlloc for further procesing. ReadFile reads at once just 2 501 566 399 bytes and it takes less than 1 second. I have 24 GB RAM on my notebook with fast SSD NVMe M.2 Samsung 960 PRO (seq. read/write 1800MB/s). I know I can read whole data with three reads but prefer to read all data at once.

Comment: The OS may be using some of your RAM for other applications (including the OS).  Did you allocate all of the memory before reading?

Comment: @Thomas
Yes, I allocated 6 796 533 695 bytes with VirtualAlloc without any problem. Still I have about 12 GB RAM available.
I tryied to read file in three reads, but there is a problem. I can't increase DWORD pointer to read data into allocated memory because of the 32 bit DWORD boundary.

Answer (score 1):

For your first pass and not optimized, I recommend using `std::vector` and `std::ifstream`.

**For Binary Data:**

```
std::ifstream input_data("my_file.dat" | ios::binary);
std::vector<DataType> data_from_file(DATA_ITEMS_TO_READ);
input_data.read((char *) data_from_file.begin(),
                 sizeof(Data_Type) * DATA_ITEMS_TO_READ);
```

**For textual data:**

```
std::ifstream input_data("my_file.txt");
std::vector<DataType> data_from_file;
Data_Type datum;
while (input_data >> datum)
{
  data_from_file.push_back(datum);
}
```

*Where `DataType` is the type of the data, e.g. `int`, `char`, `DWORD`.*

If the input is too slow, it can be optimized.  Get the remainder of the project working robust and correctly before optimizing the file reading.